# How to run e2e Angular tests with Playwright?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, e2e-testing, playwright, angular-schematics

I would like run end-to-end (e2e) browser tests for my Angular application using [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/). However, as of November 2021, I have not been able to find an Angular Schematic for Playwright.

For example, there is an official Angular Schematic for [Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/cypress-schematic). This enables running Cypress e2e tests using the command:

```sh
ng e2e
```

Is there a way to run Angular e2e tests with Playwright without writing an Angular Schematic? Or is there an Angular Schematic for Playwright that I missed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To launch a server during the tests, use the `webServer` option in the configuration file.

```js
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  webServer: {
    command: 'npx ng serve',
    port: 4200,
    timeout: 120 * 1000,
  },
};
export default config;
```

The port gets then passed over to Playwright as a `baseURL` when creating the context

```js
// test.spec.ts
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
test('test', async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
  // baseURL is taken directly from your web server,
  // e.g. http://localhost:4200
  await page.goto(baseURL + '/bar');
  // Alternatively, just use relative path, because baseURL is already
  // set for the default context and page.
  // For example, this will result in http://localhost:4200/foo
  await page.goto('/foo');
});
```

Then just run the tests with the `npx playwright test` command.

Comment: Thank you @yevhen-laichenkov for pointing out the `webServer` config option! Playwright almost makes it *too* easy. :)

Comment: Hi @YevhenLaichenkov could you give any hint regarding to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942914/cannot-run-e2e-tests-with-playwright-on-angular-12-app